# Add Google Map to a button of bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I try to put the bottom navigation bar under Google Map and I can't. When I tap the second button of navigation bar I want to open google map fragment but the bar stays at the bottom. Does anyone know how it can be done?

Here is an example of exactly what I want:

[image: Example of working navigation]

Answer (score 0):

My app uses a bottom navigation layout and loads up three fragments (on one of them is a google map fragment), hence the bottom navigation menu stays there for all the three fragment of the app!

If you want to have a screen where the bottom navigation isn't present, why not use an activity with a layout without a bottom navigation view for that screen ? The user will just navigate back to the previous activity when the job is done.